# What is the replicating portfolio of swaptions for a constant maturity swap (CMS)?

Tags: fixed-income, derivatives, replication, cms

How do you replicate the payoff of a constant maturity swap rate?

That is, if the payoff of a contract pays the 5-year swap rate every year for 10 years, how would you replicate this payoff using swaptions?

Answer (score 4):

A good place to start is Hagan's paper [Convexity Conundrum](http://www.wilmott.com/pdfs/050118_hagan.pdf) ...available on the web.

Comment: @kmcoy : beside my answer I think that you should ask more precise questions once you have read this paper where the static no arbitrage hedging procedure is clearly exposed. Best regards

Comment: The link is apparently broken

Comment: you can find it here  :https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240133238_Convexity_Conundrums_Pricing_CMS_Swaps_Caps_and_Floors

Answer (score 0):

This is an important question and while Hagan's paper is the primary reference, actually understanding it can be a somewhat involved process. A simple and intuitive answer is not always easy to find. Here's an attempt. The payoff of a vanilla swap with (pay) fixed rate $K$ is $(S-K)*dv01$. The payoff of a CMS is just $(S-K)$. The level of the swap i.e. the $dv01$ is a non-linear function of the underlying rate $S$. Thus the CMS is a linear instrument (bright red line below) and the vanilla swap is non-linear (dark red line) in $S$. [image]The CMS payoff can be replicated by:

1. replicate the original vanilla swap with long a strike $K$ payer swaption and *short* a strike $K$ receiver swaption.
2. make a portfolio of long vanilla payer swaptions and with strikes $K+i\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a constant (say 50bps) and $i=1,...,n$ are the number of swaptions chosen, and appropriately weighted notionals
3. make a portfolio of long vanilla receiver swaptions and with strikes $K-i\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a constant (say 50bps) and $i=1,...,n$ are the number of swaptions chosen, and appropriately weighted notionals

The weights of the swaption notionals can be precisely calculated and depend on the level, $\epsilon$ and $n$. This approach, though compute intensive, is the most accurate way of calculating the CMS convexity adjustment and also has the added benefit of incorporating the swaption smile into the calculation.